# Modal Dialog Going on background

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a modal dialog which i am creating in my mainframe for showing error.

But the dialog is going in background.

By pressing Alt key i bring it in front.which is annoying. Can't figure out why this is happening!

Here is the lines of code how i am generating the dialog.

### Sourde Code :

```
m_settingsDialog = std::make_unique<SettingsDialog>(this, activeTabIndex);
m_settingsDialog->DoModal();
```

Please suggest what to do.

RC :

```
 IDD_DIALOG_SYSTEM_SETTINGS_CONTROL DIALOGEX 0, 0, 437, 191
   STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_FIXEDSY |  DS_CENTER | DS_CENTERMOUSE | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
   EXSTYLE WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT
   CAPTION "Dialog"
   FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
 BEGIN
 END
```

On Size method Impl :

```
void SettingsDialog::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
 {
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    if (!m_mfcTabCtrl)
    return;
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    m_mfcTabCtrl.MoveWindow(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
 }
```

Constructor is simple :

```
  SettingsDialog::SettingsDialog(CWnd* pParent /*= nullptr*/, int activeTabIndex /*= 0*/)
: CDialog(SettingsDialog::IDD, pParent)
, m_activeTabIndex(activeTabIndex)
  {

  }
```

Comment: Pretty sure to make it app-modal you don't want to set the `pParentWnd` parameter when inheritance-constructing down through `CDialog`. In short, that `this` should not be required to push through to `CDialog::CDialog`. A null parent CWnd object will make the dialog modal to the application main window  (assuming your dialog resource script is setup properly; a big assumption since you've provided near-nothing). Further, I honestly see no sense in making this via a unique-ptr either, but I doubt that is related to your problem.

Comment: There is dockable pane inside the dialog.i thought it requires a frame.so passed the parentWnd. Now removed the param but still the modal dialog is going to background.

Comment: SettingsDialog dialog;
dialog.DoModal();
Tried this way. But still in background.

Comment: You can try SetWindowPos(..) before DoModal() to bring the Dialog in front.

Comment: m_settingsDialog->SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
m_settingsDialog->DoModal();
Is this what you mean?? 
Did that. But still no luck.

Comment: There is something wrong in your dialog. You can't show any code so there is no way to tell.

Comment: The RC code for the dialog and the constructor and Onsize method implementation i shared in the edited code. Can you please see if this can make it readable to you. If you want to see any more code for the dialog i can update. Please mention. Thanks

Comment: Then try SetWindoPos() in SetttingDialog::OnInitDialog().

Comment: @TomTom: A modal dialog always shows up in front of its owning window. If it doesn't, there's something wrong with the ownership. Calling `SetWindowPos` won't fix that.

Comment: `DS_FIXEDSY` is typo, won't let you compile. Also show any relevant code in `OnInitDialog`

Comment: @Tom Tom SetWindowPos in SettingDialog::OnInitDialog worked.Can you reply as an answer so that i can mark is solved. Thanks

Comment: @IInspectable: He probably show the Error Dialog from a Thread, with no owning window. SetWindowPos works in this case.

Comment: @TomTom: No, it doesn't work. It merely masks the bug. It doesn't fix the core issue, and when the user decides to click another window, you're back to square one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a glitch in MFC-Architecture (Link to MS-Connect [1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788540/mfc-cdialog-domodal-cant-show-window-if-parent-window-message-queue-is-busy)]. You can try SetWindoPos() in SetttingDialog::OnInitDialog().

```
SettingDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
   :
   SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW); 
   :
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.

Comment: You need to stop the madness. You cannot safely construct a cross-thread window hierarchy. Hacking it to pass some superficial testing isn't going to help. Fix the issue by setting the appropriate owner, and moving the GUI onto a single thread.

Comment: @Iinspectable. Ok comment accpepted for Cross-thread. But there is glitch in CWnd::RunModalLoop()  until Alt-Key is Pressed. So my solution is a simple, clean and sure workaround for the problem the OP asked. See:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788540/mfc-cdialog-domodal-cant-show-window-if-parent-window-message-queue-is-busy